# Showing and hiding text in response to a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

The code below does this. When I click the button for the first time, it shows the respective text. And when I click the same button again, it fades out and fades in. However, I want the respective text to disappear if the button is clicked the second time instead of fading out and then fading in.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.info').click(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <a class="info" p style="font-size:30px" href="javascript:void(0);">header 1</a>
        <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">header 2</a>
        <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">header 3</a>
        <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 3</h1>
    </div>
```

It should start like this:

header1

header2

header3

When I click header1, it should be like this:

header1

text1

header2

header3

And when I click header 1 again, it should be like this:

header1

header2

header3

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fadeToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle) to toggle the display with fade effect

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <a class="info" p style="font-size:30px" href="javascript:void(0);">header 1</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">header 2</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="info" href="javascript:void(0);">header 3</a>
  <h1 class="infoText" style="display:none">text 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What does next() do? I'm trying to understand these functions but I'm having just a hard time...

Comment: In the click handler `this` refers to the clicked `info` element, now you want to show the next sibling element of the clicked element - [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) returns the next sibling element of the current element

Comment: The next sibling element is the text?

Comment: @JaeKim it is the `h1` element

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle() for this purpose. It will hide the element if it is already shown, otherwise it will shows the element.

```
$('.info').click(function(){
     $(this).next().toggle("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.info').click(function(){
    //$(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).next().toggle("slow");
});
```

Use toggle to hide and show something

AS per suggestion of @Tushar

```
$('.info').click(function(){
    //$(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Use `fadeToggle` instead of `toggle` as OP is trying to fade the element

Comment: @Tushar i think toggle will do the job..but that for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle() Function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/bv45x2ts/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.info').click(function() {
      var _self = $(this);

      if(_self.hasClass("active")) {
          _self.next().fadeOut("slow");
         _self.removeClass("active");
      } else {
           _self.next().fadeIn("slow");         
          _self.addClass("active");
      }

  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/gte579y8/)